# Element data is undefined right after it checked to be defined

Tags: javascript

The image is self-explanatory

[image]

I'm using `Symfony`'s `encore` for the Webpack. Got this weird error and placed an Id for the form to check it explicitly in console, and saw the data('callback-event') exists for the form, before and after function triggers.

Comment: The funny part is that it actually works (the `event` invoked) and I had other errors inside the event (which catched by the promise `.catch` callback and I thought the error is `event` not being defined. On the other hand, how's this possible? is it just a chrome deBUGger's BUG?

Comment: i would do a couple of console checks: `typeof($form.data('callback-event')` and just for fun, what happens if you do `!==` instead of `!=`?

Comment: @wazz Done every check you think of, this is probably a debugger bug as I mentioned. Cause it works, and worked for almost 1 year. it was a promise catch for an undefined index inside of it that pointed me to this...

Comment: Well glad that's sorted out.